# Keep summation sign in fraction

Tags: math-mode, fractions

In Overleaf, I have the following formula:

```
\[ \frac{sum_{1}^{d_i} P(W_i|T_k) }{sum_{1}^{k}sum_{1}^{d_i} P(W_i|T_k)}\]
```

Which looks as follows:

[image]

However, instead of the word sum in the numerator and denominator, I would like to have the actual symbol.

How could I do this?

Comment: Try `\sum` instead of `sum`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
\[ \frac{\sum_{1}^{d_i} P(W_i|T_k) }{\sum_{1}^{k}\sum_{1}^{d_i} P(W_i|T_k)}\]
```